# 2005 Mazda Premacy mid range stutter, hesitation

Tags: engine, mazda, misfire, hesitation

I have a 2005 Premacy that has developed a mid range stutter or hesitation. 150k and regularly serviced, though by a local mechanic, not a Mazda dealer. It threw a fault a week ago, P2177, which I have cleared and not reoccured. Have replaced plugs, removed and cleaned the intake manifold, including the PCV valve and MAP/MAF and IAT. Coils have been tested as ok by autoelectrian. Visually checked what I can and haven't found anything obviously amiss. Borrowed a decent scan tool and a test drive hasn't shown any faults. However, the issue remains. Car drives fine under 3500 rpm, and switching to manual seems easier to drive past the hesitation. After around 5500 rpm everything frees up again. Catylitic converter is potentially needing replacement (sometimes a gunpowder smell) but this comes on suddenly so I don't think it is the cause. The car hangs onto second a bit longer that it should, and the other odd thing is the car seems to run quite cool, will at times reach mid temp range but will drift back down to cool while driving. This seems to be a reasonably common Mazda issue, but not sure if the Mazda 3/6 recommendations apply to the Premacy.

Comment: The o2 sensors or ignition coil? My camaro had the same stuttering problem and would rev high as crap but not shift. Also the plugs. A shop said they replaced mine but they obviously did not. Also you say gunpowder? I'm familiar with the smell but not exactly sure what could cause it

Comment: Coil packs tested ok, O2 range seemed ok on the scan tool. Will need to do another diagnostic run and review. It feels like something 'kicks in' then out again as it comes on quickly and consistently. Forgot to mention that we removed the swirl flaps while we had the manifold off as these were very lose and rattling, as advised by a Mazda mechanic.

Comment: After a 400 km trip through a couple of mountain passes (had to get the car back from where it threw the check light) I am still struggling to identify what the fault may be. Driving in manual seems to be able to push through the hesitation, it almost feels as if it is shifting  related. It feels similar to the momentary drop in power when the trans shifts, but longer. Temperature seems to be related, so I think I will try and isolate the cool running engine temp.